# pseudo-random function in c?

Tags: c++, c

I am reading book called the c programming language by Brian W.Kernighan and Dennis M.Ritchie. I cannot understand the function that is written in the book for generating pseudo-random number it is like this;

```
unsigned long int next = 1;

int rand(void)
{
    next = next * 1103515243 + 12345;
    return (unsigned int)(next / 65536) % 32768;
}

void srand(unsigned int seed)
{
    next = seed;
}
```

I also tried my self. But I only came up with the following observations

> 65536 = is the value of 16 bit unsigned + 1 bit
>   32768 = is the value of
>    16 bit signed + 1 bit

but I am not able to figure out the whole process .
This is the book written by the legends and I want to understand this book.
Please if anybody can help me to figure out this problem I will feel very very fortunate.

Comment: The observation `65536 = is the value of 16 bit unsigned` is wrong. Perhaps you meant `65535`.

Comment: @barakmanos Not really helpful comment. 65536 is 2^16 or the maximum of unsigned 16bit values plus one. 32768 is 2^15 or the maximum of signed 16 bit values plus one.

Comment: Hint: unsigned overflow is well-defined behaviour. :)

Comment: what part you do not understand? Actually even something as simple as `stupidPRNG(){return 0;}` is a pseudo random number generator

Comment: @SimonKraemer: 65536 cannot be represented with 16 bits!!!

Comment: Pseudo-random does not mean "almost random". It rather means "definite but with some 'good' statistical properties". You should google about LCG (Linear Congruential Generators).

Comment: what is your actual problem here??

Comment: @barakmanos And where exactly did I write it could be represented with 16 bits?

Comment: @ShivankSagar: 16 bit signed goes from -32768 to +32767, 16 bit unsigned from 0 to 65535

Comment: Does not K&R explain it?

Comment: You could write this `return (unsigned int)(next/65536) % 32768;` as this: `(unsigned int)(next >> 16) & 0xFFFF`

So this line is only ment to take only the upper 16 bit of the 32 bit integer calculated before.

Comment: @SimonKraemer I think it's `&& 0x7fff`, but otherwise correct.

Comment: oops sorry i think i made a big mistake.Thanks for the corrections i am editing my question again

Comment: All that there is to understand is this: PRNGs generate sequences of numbers which look random statistically, but are in fact deterministic; the procedure you have there was designed to have the PRNG property by somebody who knew what he was doing.

Comment: @dhke Yeah, I got it wrong there. So it's only the last 15 bits

Comment: Your comment "And where exactly did I write it could be represented with 16 bits" makes you look ridiculous, since everyone can see that this is exactly what you wrote before you edited the question and changed it!!!

Comment: @SimonKraemer: "16 bit signed goes from -32768 to +32767" Not always. C allows for other representations of signed integers than 2s complement.

Comment: @tobi303: A constant generator is **not** a (P)RNG. Randomness requires more than a single, constant value. By the name, that would be the standard library's functions, which adds some [requirements](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.2.1) to `rand`.

Comment: @Olaf Could you explain this please? I don't really know what you mean.

Comment: @Olaf I didnt claim that it is a good one. How would you know, if you do not know the implementation, but only the interface? `double stupidPRNG()` looks reasonable... you could only test it, but then 100 (or even 1000) zeros is just as likely as any other sequence :P

Comment: @SimonKraemer: What about "C allows for other representations ..." is not clear? By "C" I obviously mean the C [standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html)

Comment: @tobi303: Because it does not quack like a duck! `rand` is well defined (and K&R is about that particular standard library function) and the term (P)RNG implies that it delivers not just a constant, because of lacking the `R` in **R**andom.

Comment: @barakmanos I would like to have a revision history for comments. My first post was "@barakmanos Not really helpful comment." and my edit was to add the rest of it.

Comment: @Olaf This part was clear. I was refering to "other representations of signed integers than 2s complement". I can't imagine what you mean by that. Especially as I stated this for 16-bit integers. For my understanding a bit is always binary and therefore 2s complement.

Comment: @SimonKraemer: A bit is a bit, just 1 and 0. You might be thinking about _binary_ (i.e. multi-bit) values. Their interpreation is completely left to the human. What makes the bit-pattern `01000001` the letter `A`? Why not just try [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations)?

Comment: @Olaf Yeah, forgot about that. So the only exception for the ranges would be Base -2.

Comment: Don't read K&R, it is an old obsolete book full with errors. They don't know the C language as it is standardized today. For example the line `(unsigned int)(next / 65536) % 32768;` is incorrect on a 16 bit system. Surprisingly, as the book was written in the 16 bit era. On a 16 bit or smaller system `(unsigned int)(next / 65536)` is of type unsigned int, but `an_unsigned_int % 32768` implicitly converts it back to `long`, because the literal 32768 is of type long. So the cast is superfluous and the result of the expression will be of type long on some systems.

Comment: Summary: In order to read K&R, you must know enough C to explain the C language to K&R, so you can tell them where they went wrong, on pretty much every page. Use a pencil and correct the K&R book, should be: `return (int) (next / 65536 % 32768);`. Operator associativity makes the inner-most parenthesis superfluous. Of course K&R likely didn't know that either, since their own operator precedence table is incorrect as well.

Answer (score 5):

This hasn't an accepted answer yet, so let's try one.

As noted by Basile Starynkevitch, what is implemented here is a pseudo-random number generator (RNG) from the class of [linear congruential generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) (LCGs). These in general take the form of a sequence

```
X := (a * X + c) mod m
```

The starting value for `X` is called the *seed* (same as in the code). Of course `c < m` and `a < m`. Often also `a << c`. Both `c` and `m` are usually large numbers chosen so that the whole sequence does reasonably well in the [*spectral test*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_test), but you probably don't have to care about that to understand the basic mode of operation. If you are a little bit into number theory, you will probably see that the sequence repeats after a while (it is periodic).

Random numbers are generated, by first seeding `X` with a starting seed. For each generated number, the sequence is cycled and a subset of the bits of `X` are returned.

In the code from the question, `a = 1103515245`, `c = 12345`, and 
`m` is implicitly `pow(2, 8 * sizeof(unsigned long))` by virtue of unsigned integer overflow. These are also the values [ISO/IEC 9899](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/standards.html), i.e. the C language standard suggests.

With this known, the first pitfall is probably this statement:

```
return (unsigned int)(next / 65536) % 32768;
```

Kernighan and Ritchie probably thought that using only simple arithmetic is more readable and more portable than using bit masks and bit shifts. The above is equivalent to

```
return (unsigned int)(next >> 16) & 0x7fff
```

which selects bits 16-30 from `next`. You get back a pseudo-random number in the range `[0;32767]`. The bit range is also the one suggested in the C standard.

**WARNING**: It is well known that this LCG does --while widely deployed, because it's noted in the standard-- not produce very good pseudo-random numbers (the version in GLIBc is even worse). Distinctively, it is absolutely unsafe to use for cryptographic applications. With the few number of random bits, I would not even use it for any [Monte Carlo method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method), because results may be severely skewed by the quality of the RNG.

So in short: Try to understand it: yes, you are welcome. Use it for anything: no.

Comment: `32768` is _not_ equivalent to `0x7ffff`, because on a 16 bit system the former is of type `long` and the latter is of type `unsigned int`. This is because of the rules about how integer literals are given types, see the table in C11 6.4.4.1. Meaning that the first snippet performs the modulo calculation on type long, while the latter performs the bitwise AND on type int. It doesn't seem to make any difference in this code, but there's a great potential for subtle bugs here, especially when int is 16 bits. Use the `UL` suffix for the literals to avoid such bugs.

Comment: @Lundin In never stated that the numbers are equivalent. But if we are nitpicking: `32768UL` would be `0x10000UL`. The actually typo are the 4 f in the original answer, there should only be 3. Of course you are correct wrt to type conversion.

Answer (score 4):

[Pseudo Random Number Generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) are a very complex subject. You could learn it for years, and get a PhD on it. As commented, read also about [linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) (it looks like your code is an *example* in some C standard)

In C on POSIX systems, you have [random(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/random.3.html) (and also [lrand48(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/lrand48.3.html), sort-of obsolete); In C++11 you have [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random)

The `/65536` operation might be compiled as `>>16` a right shift of 16 bits.
The `%32768` operation could be [optimized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) as a bitmask (same as `&0x7fff`) keeping 15 least bits.

Comment: You might want to mention that  the code is exactly an implementation of the "standard" C pseudo-random number generator LCG as suggested by C99/C11 including the exact same bitmask.

Comment: I didn't know that, and I believe that many `libc` have a better PRNG

Comment: I agree with you, but the question is not about PRNGs in general but about that particular piece of code ;-)